# Problem with with org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

I am getting this when I try to set up the environment using maven:

I had to execute it using debug to get more details that I attach next:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (exec-npm-cache-clean) on project global-home: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (exec-npm-cache-clean) on project global-home: Command execution failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:276)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:660)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:265)
    ... 22 more
```

This happens only with executing the command
mvn clean install

or when I import the project as Maven Project and I execute
Maven -> Update Project...

This is the segment of the pom.xml file:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>exec-npm-cache-clean</id>
                <phase>clean</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>npm</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>cache</argument>
                        <argument>clean</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>exec-npm-install-test</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>npm</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>install</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>exec-npm-install</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>npm</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>install</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>exec-grunt-build-test</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>grunt</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>build</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>exec-grunt-build</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>grunt</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>build</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <!--<execution>
                <id>exec-npm-install-phantomjs</id>
                <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>npm</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>install</argument>
                        <argument>phantomjs</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>-->
            <!--<execution>
                <id>exec-export-phantomjs</id>
                <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>export</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>
                            PHANTOMJS_BIN=${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp-source/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs;
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>-->
            <execution>
                <id>exec-grunt-testCI</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                    <environmentVariables>
                        <PHANTOMJS_BIN>
                            ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp-source/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
                        </PHANTOMJS_BIN>
                    </environmentVariables>
                    <executable>grunt</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>testCI</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp-source</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: does it work when you run the maven build from the command line (outside of the IDE)?

Comment: No. I get the same error from command line.

Comment: looks like executing npm doesn't work. Did you try to put in an absolute path to the executable instead of just `npm`?